# how to make this block on html and css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

How to make this block? I don't know how to make the grey background at the end.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide
[a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
, along with your desired
 results, your actual
 results, including all errors
, and demonstrate your research and your attempts
 and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: You could probably do this with a gradient on the background color of the block. See: [Using CSS gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_images/Using_CSS_gradients#creating_hard_lines). You need to read the page from the top, to understand how to create a hard line between two colors.

Comment: use css3 grid or flexbox.

Comment: @iorgv I think Akbaraliev can find your answer. It's more likely that either the problem was solved and Akbaraliev lost interest, or just didn't fancy reacting to comment and answers. That happens a lot here.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you for your reaction. Indeed, this does happen a lot here. I was about to ask someone whether the OP gets a notification after the question is closed, or not.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware in general, can the OP mark the answer as the chosen one even after the question is closed?

Comment: @iorgv Sorry, I don't know that. It can still be up- and downvoted. I didn't yet upvote it because the gray block in the background doesn't touch the right margin, and disappears when the window get narrower. Why not apply the gradient to the background of class `outer` or `wrap`?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I might be able to fix the gray block in the background to touch the right margin. I made it disappear because I had no clue what it has to look like on a narrower window. I didn't apply the gradient to the background of class `outer` or `wrap`, because on the image (that the OP linked), it's only on the images - or I don't quite get what you are referring to....

Comment: @Akbaraliev Here are some useful links tackling the problem: a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IT_b15hE6uY&ab_channel=MrWebKing), my [codepen where I make a responsive layout using only flexbox](https://codepen.io/creme332/pen/PoLwpdL). The high-resolution image of the design is available [here](https://search.muz.li/NTRiMjI1MjUz)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```css
.outer {
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  max-width: 300px;
  float: left;
}

.inner h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.inner h2 span {
  color: #ea7866;
}

.inner p {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: gray;
  text-align: justify;
}

.inner button {
  font-family: Times, serif;
  color: white;
  background: #ea7866;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 980px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.wrap span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 200px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.city-container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 195px;
  height: 235px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-grid;
  margin: 10px;
}

.city-container img {
  width: 195px;
  height: 235px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: -235px;
}

.city-container:before {
  width: 195px;
  height: 235px;
  background: linear-gradient(6deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 9;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .wrap:before {
    content: '';
    width: 41%;
    height: 310px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    right: 0;
    top: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Top <span>Destinations</span> In The World</h2>

    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be the distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout from it.</p>

    <button>Discover More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="city-container"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"><span>Cuba City</span></div>
    <div class="city-container"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"><span>Paris</span></div>
    <div class="city-container"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"><span>Japan</span></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm leaving now, but I still think this answer can be improved, if you're interested in that. I'll check back in 4 or 5 hours.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware sure, do so, I'm interested, many thanks.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I now fixed the gray block to start from the right margin, it wasn't a big deal. I'm waiting for your further suggestions and improvements. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I agree that it is not clear what should happen in a narrower window. The question simply doesn't tell us.